# How to display Multiple data in different Cards dynamically. in react native

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native. I have created Two screen from first screen I am sending data from API to next screen. and here in next I want to show that data in different different cards. for example . if I am getting two data like ID = 1 and ID = 2 . so In this I want to show Two cards named ID1 and ID2. so on if in future suppose user will get 100 IDs so in next screen 100 IDs should create dynamically.  please help thanks.

here is my code

```
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state ={
    Email:"",
    data:this.props.route.params.data,
  }
  render() {
    const route = this.props
    const data = this.data

    return (

          <View style={{alignItems:"center", justifyContent:"center",height:140, width:"90%", marginTop:30}}>

    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("FormItems")}>
          <Card center middle shadow style={{ height:80, width:"100%" }} >
          <Text medium height={15} size={14}style={{ fontWeight: "bold", paddingRight:190}}>
            {this.props.route.params.data}
                    {'\n'} 
                    {this.props.route.params.data}
                    </Text>
                    </Card>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
 );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on the structure of your data. Basically, it will look something like this. Assuming your data passed contains an array of objects, you can map the objects to an n number of cards. Instead of  using a single card, do something like

```
{this.props.route.params.data.map(item =>
    <Card>
        <Text>{item.label}</Text>
        <Text>{item.description}</Text>
    </Card>
)}
```

Comment: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.  => this error is coming

Comment: @SohilShaikh Can you retry with the updated syntax? Either remove the {} or add a return statement in the map function.

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...this.props.route.params.data.map...') => now this error is coming

Comment: @SohilShaikh What is the content in data?

Comment: Id=1, name =xyz like this